# How to get multiple Paperclip URLs as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I use Paperclip to handle photo uploads to my application, whereas a certain model can have many photos. So far everything works well, however, I **need** all photo URLs injected in my view as JSON **using a helper** method.

So, I have a model:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  ...

    def return_all_photos
        self.photos.each do |photo|
          photo.image.url(:medium)
        end
    end
  ...
end
```

And a helper:

```
module ModelsHelper

   def data_as_json(item)
   {
     ...

     gallery_photos: item.return_all_photos

     ...

    }.to_json
   end
end
```

I don't get any errors, but not the behavior as expected. Instead of having an array with the URLs in the JSON data, I get an array of objects in the JSON data, which looks like the following (screenshot from my devtools):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuoQc.png)

Does anyone have an idea what causes the issue and why the according URLs are not returned?

Comment: In `rails console`, does `Model.first.photos.first.image.url(:medium)` give you what you are expecting? Perhaps you have to cast it to a `String`? `photo.image.url(:medium).to_s`. Another thing, you might want to consider `map` over `each` for this case: `self.photos.map { |p| p.image.url(:medium).to_s }`

Comment: @ddubs Sorry for the late response! `Model.first.photos.first.image.url(:medium)` indeed gives me what I'm expecting. However, this only gives me the last image url. When I do `Model.first.photos.image.url(:medium)` I get an error saying that image is an undefined method. I basically need all image url (in an array). I will give your other suggestions a shot now!

Comment: `self.photos.map { |p| p.image.url(:medium)}` actually did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I added that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using map instead of each to return an array:

```
def return_all_photos
  self.photos.map { |p| p.image.url(:medium) }
end
```